# No Writing posible: SSL / TLS with AsyncSocket for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, asyncsocket

I am working with the AsyncSocket for iOS. (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

I wrote my own Class to handle the connection with AsyncSocket. I wrote the method writeDate: (NSString *) data and add the AsyncSocket Callbackfunctions in my Class.

```
-(void)writeData: (NSString*) data
{
    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
    NSData *raw = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [socket writeData:raw withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
}
```

The connection works great and if I'm trying to send a message in "didConnectToHost" after [sock startTLS:setting] it works.

But if I try to send a message with my own method (writeDate: (NSString *) data) and the call:

```
MyClass *test = [MyClass sharedSSLConnection];
[test writeData:@"test"];
```

It failed. I think the problem is, that the Handshake isn't ready when the method want's to sent a message on the socket. But how can I solve this? I did not find any solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error massage is (willDisconnectWithError:Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9844 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9844.)"). But onSocketDidSecure is not called before the code in writeData is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might recommend that your `MyClass` store the data and wait until the state is ready `onSocketDidSecure` and send it then?